YAxis labels in the MPAndroidChart library
I have a chart that has only two values (2 and 10 in this case). I'd like to see those values as labels on the y axis. But as you can see the chart shows 0 and 10. I've set the label count as 2 and chart's minimum and maximum is 0 and 10 respectively. It seems this is not doable in this library. We can only set the label count, not the exact labels.  Has anyone done this before?


Please share your code which you have tried so far.
